# Why does a yeast infection burn?

Tags: bacteria, yeast-infection

I am new to this site and not entirely sure how much background knowledge I should posses in order to ask questions.

However, I am curious as to why a yeast infection burns and itches? What is the bacteria doing to my body that causes such a reaction?